# React-lazy-loadin-image-component fade not disappear on mobile

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, react-lazy-load

Im using react-lazy-loading-image-component library in this site if you scroll down you can see that the image fade is not disappearing after the image fully load someone knows to to fix that (it’s happening only in mobile)

https://toval-recycle.vercel.app/